# How can I enchant a sword to level 500?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I play Minecraft on PE edition. I want to get a sharpness 500 sword with a command block. How do I do this? I have already tried `/enchant @p sharpness 500` while holding the sword, but that didn't work. If it needs a mod, please tell me the mod name.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use /enchant to enchant something that can’t be enchanted like you want in an anvil. You will have to get an application that can edit data values in Mcpe.https://download.cnet.com/Inventory-Editor-for-Minecraft/3000-2121_4-77538475.html

Comment: To Raderth, what is the application?

Comment: https://download.cnet.com/Inventory-Editor-for-Minecraft/3000-2121_4-77538475.html